# What is the best data structure to represent a set partition?

Tags: c++, data-structures

By a "set partition", specifically a set partition of {1,2,...,n}, I mean a collection of nonempty sets of integers between 1 and n such that each integer is in exactly one of the sets, and does not occur more than once in that set. Think of it as a way of dividing all the numbers between 1 and n into an arbitrary number of boxes, where both the boxes and their contents are unordered.

I have two different functions I need to compute for these kinds of object, which I will give as pseudocode below. I can make do without interleaving these functions, so it would be fine to have two different data structures for them, but if one structure is good for both, that would be nice. The time complexity of converting to or from the data structure is basically irrelevant compared to the time these functions take.

The first function is as follows:

```
setPartition FunctionA(setPartition partition):
     choose a random integer i between 1 and n
     choose a part P of partition uniformly at random 
     if i is in P:
          return(partition)
     else:
          for j in P:
               do a computation depending only on i and j, not on P or partition
          if [condition depending on those computations]:
               remove i from the part it is currently in
               add i to P
               return(partition)
          else:
               return(partition)
```

Notice here that in the step where we remove i from its current part, we need to remove that set from the collection if it becomes empty. We also cannot choose i by first choosing a random part and then a random element, since that does not give the right distribution, so looking up which part i is in is probably necessary. (We could choose a random part if we did it with each part having probability proportional to its size, but that'd require us to know the size of each part.)

The second is:

```
setPartition FunctionB(setPartition partition):
    with probability p:
        choose two distinct parts P and Q of partition uniformly at random
        for i in P and j in Q:
            do a computation depending only on i and j, not on P, Q, or partition
        if [condition depending on those computations]:
            merge parts P and Q into a single part
            return(partition)
        else:
            return(partition)
    otherwise:
        choose a part P of partition uniformly at random
        choose a subset Q of P uniformly at random (i.e. each element is in Q w.p. 50%)
        for i in Q and j in (P minus Q):
            do a computation depending only on i and j, not on P, Q, or partition
        if [condition depending on those computations]:
            remove the elements of Q from P
            create a new part whose elements are Q
            return(partition)
        else:
            return(partition)
```

Again, bear in mind that the merging of parts can't leave an empty part lying around -- the set partition must always consist of *nonempty* sets.

These functions are both run in a big loop modifying a single set-partition, say, a million times, or two million times, so obviously doing this by modifying in place seems like a good idea. I'm doing this for n around 2000 or so, so using more memory for faster computations is a good tradeoff, I think.

I've already implemented this once in R, representing the partitions as lists of lists in the obvious way, but that just isn't fast enough for the amount of computations I need, so I decided to reimplement it in C++. So I want to make sure I'm using the right data structure to begin with, so I don't have to reimplement it all a third time.

Comment: For the range of [1, ... , 2000] which I consider as not that big, you can use an array (or `std::vector`) of `int` with 2000 elements. Each _index_ represents an element of the range where the elements of the array (or vector) represent the index of the set it belongs to. Of course, there should be a value to represent that the element of range belongs to non set (maybe, -1). This would make the look-up very fast as long as you want to find out to which set a certain number belongs to. For the opposite direction, i.e. which numbers a partition contains - a `std::vector` for each set.

Comment: For the latter, a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` could be considered as well. (That should be subject of a profiling.) A `std::vector` supports cache locality but finding something specific is O(N). A `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` have O(ld N) or even O(1) (average case) but their cache locality is worse. So, it depends which advantage pays off, and that depends of the average use case.

Comment: this^^. There is no "best". It always depends on the use case, and the only way to know is to measure.

Comment: If you encapsulate it properly, you can fiddle with the exact implementation of the partition container after you have written the code for the computation. I would go for something like `std::map` for lookups "which partition this number is in" and `std::multiset` for "what are the members of this partition" and a `std::set` for keeping track of partition ids and all those have to be updated together.